# Consistently show project icon while debugging c# console applications in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, icons, console-application

I am debugging a lot of .net5 console applications in one solution simultaneously, often changing which ones are started. Every console application opens a new windows which means that the windows taskbar gets another entry added. To make it easier to spot which ones are started I want all the applications to show custom icons in the taskbar.

As an example I use this [icon](https://site.findicons.com/icon/24540/money) assigned to the projects via **Properties** -> **Application**.

The first problem is that the "first" application when debugging always is shown as the default icon with the text "C:\", regardless of what icon is set in the project settings.

The second is that sometimes even if the icon is accepted by visual studio it is never actually shown until the console is ran as after the application has been published (dotnet publish).

The assigned icons always show up correctly in the task manager.

How can I consistently show icons for all my console applications while debugging a solution?

Edit:

I found out that if the application is an asp.net console application, the icon never shows in the taskbar ever. Standard .net console applications seems to always have their icons shown correctly when not ran as "first" application as stated above, so the question still stands.

Comment: you would have easier time to changing window title - `Console.Title`

Comment: I have already set window title per application which works fine.